# org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException:

Tags: java

I'm using TestNG version 7.5.0 and a data provider along with xlsx excel for Test Data. Can someone guide me with this method matcher exception?

```
org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException: 
com.sfe.testscripts.PaymentPageTest.stripePayment(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.InterruptedException] has no parameters defined but was found to be using a data provider (either explicitly specified or inherited from class level annotation).
    Data provider mismatch
    Method: stripePayment([Parameter{index=0, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=1, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=2, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=3, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=4, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=5, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=6, type=int, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=7, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=8, type=int, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=9, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}])
    Arguments: [(java.lang.String) voyid40057@sinyago.com,(java.lang.String) Testing@143,(java.lang.String) Adhitya,(java.lang.String) Ashwin,(java.lang.String) Shristi,(java.lang.String) Manager,(java.lang.String) 1,(java.lang.String) Cosmetics,(java.lang.String) 3,(java.lang.String) 234klk]
        at org.testng.internal.reflect.DataProviderMethodMatcher.getConformingArguments(DataProviderMethodMatcher.java:46)
        at org.testng.internal.Parameters.injectParameters(Parameters.java:886)
        at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:37)
        at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:945)
        at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:193)
        at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
        at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:808)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:603)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:429)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:423)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:383)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:326)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1249)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1092)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1060)
        at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

```java
    package com.sfe.testscripts;
    
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    
    import com.sfe.baseclass.BaseClass;
    import com.sfe.dataproviders.DataProviders;
    import com.sfe.pageobjects.ProfilePageObjects;
    import com.sfe.pageobjects.SignInPageObjects;
    
    public class PaymentPageTest extends BaseClass {
    
        private SignInPageObjects singInPage;
        private ProfilePageObjects profilePage;
    
        @Parameters("browser")
        @BeforeMethod
        public void setup(String browser) {
            launchApp(browser);
        }
        
        @AfterMethod
        public void tearDown() {
            getDriver().quit();
        }
        
        @Test(dataProvider = "data", dataProviderClass = DataProviders.class)
        public void stripePayment(String uname, String pswd, String firstName, String lastName, String companyName,
                String Designation, int country, String industry, int companysize, String taxID)
                throws InterruptedException {
            System.out.println("kjld");
            singInPage = new SignInPageObjects();
            profilePage = singInPage.getEmailSignIn(uname, pswd);
            profilePage.getProfileEditPage(firstName, lastName, companyName, Designation, country, industry, companysize,taxID);
    
        }
    }
    
    
    package com.sfe.dataproviders;
    
    import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    
    import com.sfe.utility.NewExcelLibrary;
    
    public class DataProviders {
    
        NewExcelLibrary obj= new NewExcelLibrary();
        
        
        @DataProvider(name="data")
        public Object[][] getCredentials() {
            
            int rows=obj.getRowCount("STRIPE");
            int columns=obj.getColumnCount("STRIPE");
            int actRows=rows-1;
            Object[][] data=new Object[actRows][columns];
            for(int i=0;i<actRows;i++) {
                for(int j=0;j<columns;j++) {
                    data[i][j]=obj.getCellData("STRIPE", j, i+2);
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Using Java selenium - TestNG framework.
Data Provider and excel are used for passing data from excel to actual test scripts

Problem: Browser not launched and data are not passed from excel to the test scripts. When I run the script, method mismatcher exception arises.